# Can you identify this robotic minifigure?

Tags: minifigures, minifigure-identification

I am trying to identify this minifigure.  I thought it was related to Star Wars but I can not find it there. Can you help?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE. I took a liberty updating your question by correcting image orientation.

Answer (score 7):

This is :

[sp043 : UFO Droid - Blue (Techdroid 1)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=sp043#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

Comment: Thank you so much!  I appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi Stan and welcome to Bricks.SE! Please take a mintue to check out the [tour] to learn how you can mark this answer as accepted, to show that you are satisfied with it.